# Migrate from ActionBar to ToolBar

Tags: android, compatibility, material-design, android-toolbar

I need to upgrade an app to use `Material Design`. The first thing I'm trying to do is show the new `Toolbar`, but I'm not sure on how I should do this.

I have my main `FragmentActivity` which I inflate some `menu` and do:

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.main_color)));
```

I also use `NavigationDrawer`, so I set an icon for the drawer too.

Said that, how can I achieve the same behaviour using the new `Toolbar`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just look to a [android developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html). It contains explanation with "how to"

**Shortly**

Add *Toolbar* like a *View* to your activity's layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

You should to set your *Toolbar* as an *ActionBar*

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And don't forget about styling. Add new *style.xml* to a resource dir *values-21v*, after that your *Toolbar* will be colored by your *colorPrimary*

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name=”colorPrimary”>@color/my_awesome_color</item>

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name=”colorPrimaryDark”>@color/my_awesome_darker_color</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name=”colorAccent”>@color/accent</item>

    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
     colorControlHighlight, and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

</style>
```